# How to change UICollectionViewCell's background outside of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to change iOS UICollectionViewCell background outside of the cell?

For instance, I have a view controller which implements `UICollectionViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:MY_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER];
}

- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:MY_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (condition)
    {
        [self actionOne];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else
    {        
        [self actionTwo];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Breakpoints inside of `if (condition)` statement shows, that desired lines are executed. But, sadly, cells background stays the same...

What is more, I am successfully doing practically the same thing id `UICollectionViewDataSource` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:MY_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in place of`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

EDIT: Only in `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Explanation:  `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` will get you a new cell, that you change the background color of, but that cell never gets added to the table so you won't see it. When you use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you will get a cell from the table to edit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (condition)
    {
        [self actionOne];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else
    {        
        [self actionTwo];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: check if 'cell' is nil

Comment: Checked. The cell is not nil

Comment: can you comment the lines where you call actionOne/actionTwo methods and tell me what happens

Comment: Nothing happens. It makes sense, because these methods are independent to cells...